# getting all documents with the same field value firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

long story short that I have a collection called products , in this collection every product have a document that is called category , I want to get all the products with the same category and this is the structure for it . I know that I should use `where().equalto`  , but I did not get it , any help ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Future<List<ProductModel>> getProductCategory(String category) async {
    QuerySnapshot query = await _firestore.collection(collection)
        .where("category", isEqualTo: category)
        .get();
    
    if(query.docs.isNotEmpty){
      query.docs.forEach((element) {
        productCategory.add(ProductModel.fromSnapshot(element.data()));
      });
    }
      return productCategory;
  }
```

This will return all documents which having category is equal to "eye".

Comment: `    
  Future<List<ProductModel>> getProductCategory(String category){
        _firestore.collection(collection).where("category",isEqualTo: category).get().then((result) {
          for(DocumentSnapshot procat in result.docs){
            productCategory.add(ProductModel.fromSnapshot(procat));

          }
          return productCategory;
        });
      }
`
is this supposed to work ?

Comment: No, It will not work, Im updating my answer so you can directly use it.

Comment: @FahmiSawalha i've updated my code please check it

Comment: the elemen.data() got an error , do you have a discord ?

Comment: Sorry for it but i dont have discord, Can you share version of  cloud firestore  dependency? so i'll give you quick solution.